# Use Ember.set() to set the 'content' property

Tags: ember.js

We have an issue that seems to be very similar to https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/9767. The error we get is the following:

`Error while processing route: [route-name] Assertion Failed: You must use Ember.set() to set the 'content' property (of [route]) to 'undefined'.`

So the only difference is that it complaints about 'content' instead of 'controller', and that it is trying to set it to 'undefined'. This only happens for a few users, and it seems to be mostly old Android-devices. We have managed to reproduce the error in the default browser on a device running android 2.3.4.

Does anyone have a clue to why this happens? Debugging on old android devices is a pain!

Comment: I am having the same issue, since I upgraded to Ember 1.9.1

Comment: @dferreira.pt Answered my own question, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about this question on StackOverflow, and someone else in our team have committed a fix for the issue. This line of code:

```
return self.getJSON(self.get('dataUrl'))
    .then(self.get('_modelMap').bind(self))
```

Have been changed to this:

```
return self.getJSON(self.get('dataUrl'))
    .then(function(data) {
        return self._modelMap(data);
    })
```

This was done in one of our base controllers.

Handlebars was also upgraded from v1.3.0 to v2.0.0 in the same commit. Don't know if that is required for fixing the issue though.

Hopefully this can help others with the same issue :)